# Is it possible to still grow taller after growth plates have been closed?

Tags: human-anatomy

In addition, when do we know we stop growing taller? Or we keep growing taller? 
To the first question:
Recently, I went to a doctor to have a check up, he said that my growth plates are closed and cannot grow taller anymore. True or false? Is it possible to have a second growth spurt. I am about 16.

Answer (score 2):

No, because growth only occurs at the [epiphyseal plate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyseal_plate) or growth plate. In the picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTib_fib_growth_plates.jpg), the epiphyseal plates are the two horizontal lines in the tibia and fibula, and bone growth occurs in the upward direction, or toward the middle (shaft) of the bone. Once the epiphyseal plates close, the bones can no longer elongate.

It's possible to have a second "growth spurt," but it's only because the epiphyseal plates haven't closed. David Robinson, the basketball player, was 6'7" as a senior in high school, but ended up being 7'1". The "growth spurt" is caused by the sex hormones, which is why a significant amount of growth occurs during puberty.